# Laravel FTP - Root path for windows server

Tags: laravel, ftp, windows-server-2008

I am trying to upload a file from my local to FTP server using laravel

```
'ftp' => [
        'driver' => 'ftp',
        'host' => env('FTP_HOST'),
        'username' => env('FTP_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('FTP_PASSWORD'),
        'port'  => '21',
        'passive' => false,
        'root' => 'c:/POSActiveAutoInsert/WEBSales_In/' // for example: /var/www/html/dev/images
//           
],
```

In my controller

```
Storage::disk('ftp')->put('test.txt', $file);
```

But when I run this, it says

`Root is invalid or does not exist: c:/POSActiveAutoInsert/WEBSales_In/`

I have tried FTP using Filezilla it works fine

The FTP account I am using takes you directly to `c:/POSActiveAutoInsert/WEBSales_In/` this folder. This `WEBSales_In` is the root folder for this FTP user that I am using. Can't figure out what the root path would be, or am I doing something wrong other than this.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this in your controller

```
$path = $request->your_variable_name->storeAs('text', '$file', ['disk' => 'ftp']);
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it. where should I use it? what will be 'your_variable_name'

Comment: Replace it `Storage::disk('ftp')->put('test.txt', $file);` with above code. File name like `$request->image`